# increment a counter starting from 000

Tags: ruby

Typically when you want to have a counter, you can do something like this:

```
["a","b","c"].each.with_index(0) do |_case, i|
  puts i
end
=> 0
=> 1
=> 2
```

We increment from 0. 0 is represented as a `Fixnum` in Ruby.
 000 is also represented as a Fixnum in Ruby. But I need to increment as 000,001,002,003,etc. But instead it increments from 000 to 1:

```
["a","b","c"].each.with_index(000) do |_case, i|
  puts i
end
=> 0
=> 1
=> 2
```

How get I increment 000 as 001,002,003,etc?

Comment: It is important to note the difference between a number and a representation of a number. A number is an abstract mathematical concept, represented in Ruby as some pattern of bits. It can be represented in different bases, and this representation is a string (or if in code, a literal). `000` and `0` both represent the same number. `010` as a literal in code is a representation of the number we usually write as 8. `010` can be a three-digit representation of any number greater than 1, by picking that number as a base, although Ruby restricts bases to up to 36 (e.g. `"010".to_i(24)` is 24).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formatted printing functions [`printf` and `sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
["a","b","c"].each_with_index { |_case, i| printf("%03d\n", i) }
000
001
002
```

Comment: 03 indicates padding 0 three times?

Comment: Yes. 3 indicates the field is 3 characters wide and the 0 indicates it should be zero-padded. So 04 would give you 0000, 0001, 0002 for example.

Comment: You may as well use `each_index`.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to print padded numbers then Ruby can do this for you by using string ranges. A few ways to do this:

```
puts ('001'..'005').to_a
```

or

```
('001'..'005').each { |n| puts n }
```

or

```
puts ('001'..'999').take(5)
```

All of which print:

```
#001
#002
#003
#004
#005
```